# Maven modules multi-level hierarchy

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, pom.xml, parent-pom

Is it possible to have multi-level module hierarchy in maven? 
If yes, are there any problems with it or would it work as smooth as parent-child hierarchy?

e.g.

```
parent
  |__child1
  |__child2
       |__grandchild1
       |__grandchild2
               |__greatgrandchild
```

Comment: While doing this works fine, I think you should give consideration to the complexity of it and whether or not you're just making it more complicated than it needs to be. Complexity is the enemy of maintainability...

Comment: i know this thread is old, but can we have different profiles at the parent AND the child levels?